# How to prevent a column from having spaces in google sheets?

Tags: validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I'm trying to add data validation to a column so it does not allow spaces between words. People should use camelCase in that column.

But when I'm trying to create the validation it says the space is not valid text. All there is in the input is that blank space, you can see it selected.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Text Does not contain

```
=" "
```